# Sort the option set based on the back end option set value

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have tried to sort the option set value but it is sorting based on the Alphabet, it should be sorted based on option value

I tried the below code, but not sorting based on the option set value.

```cs
QueryExpression filBusinessInventory = new QueryExpression("new_filbusinessinventoryfa");
filBusinessInventory.Criteria.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.On, dateString2);
filBusinessInventory.Criteria.AddCondition("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, "Active");
filBusinessInventory.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("createdon", "new_customer", "new_month", "new_year");
filBusinessInventory.AddOrder("new_month", OrderType.Ascending);
filBusinessInventory.Orders.Add(new OrderExpression("new_month", OrderType.Descending));
```

Need to sort the option set field "month" based on the option set value not on Alphabetic order.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering on optionset fields are done on the value of the field and not on the Alphabet.
Just add

```
filBusinessInventory.AddOrder("new_month", OrderType.Ascending);
```

without adding also

```
filBusinessInventory.Orders.Add(new OrderExpression("new_month", OrderType.Descending));
```

Comment: I tried, but it is sorting based on the Alphabets not on the option set back end value .

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data from crm as it is I.e ordering by label but when you have entity collection object in C# you can order it based on option set value.

You can also convert your entity collection object into list and apply lambda function which will give you option of ordering based on value.

Comment: I donno about that how to use that please suggest me.